# How to move all pixels down?

Tags: processing

I drew multiple white pixels on a black canvas to get a night sky. I gave the stars random positions and now want that all pixels move down in-order to imitate the movement of the earth.

I tried Translate but that doesn't seem to work with pixels.

Is there a way to move all the Pixels in the canvas down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arrayCopy(pixels, 0, pixels, width, (height - 1) * width);
```

Should solve the problem you have. For more help about arrayCopy look here: https://processing.org/reference/arrayCopy_.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the process of creating an animation is this:

- Store your state in variables, or in a buffer.
- Use those variables to draw your scene every frame.
- Change those variables over time to change your scene.

One approach is to draw your stars to a buffer. The `createGraphics()` function is your friend. Then draw that buffer to the screen using the `image()` function. Then move the y position of the buffer down by some amount each frame.

Another approach is to store your star positions in a set of variables, such as an `ArrayList` of `PVector` instances. Draw those positions to the screen, and move each one down a bit each frame.

The `translate()` function should work fine for points, and it's just another approach to the steps I outlined above. As is Tobias's answer. There are a bunch of different ways to do this. If you're still having trouble, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post. Good luck.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on creating animations in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation).